# Java: automatically detecting input file path

Tags: java, file, input, path

I need to create a program which gets its input from a file. What do I need to use in order to automatically find the current path and then search for the input file?

Example: I place my main file in `C:/*pathname*/` and my input file name is `INPUT.txt`. How can I make my program automatically find the `C:/*pathname*/INPUT.txt` path to get its input?

Comment: NIO.2 can make this pretty easy: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html

Comment: You will have to recursively search for INPUT.txt in 'C:' drive also called walking the file tree. More info: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html

Comment: Is your input file always in the same folder as your program? Then you can use relative paths `new File(./INPUT.txt)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion in this case, to find your file. You start the searching process in the current/given directory, by checking if your current file matches the given file name. If you find a directory, you continue the recursion searching process in this directory.

```
private static final File findFile(final String rootFilePath, final String fileToBeFound) {

    File rootFile = new File(rootFilePath);
    File[] subFiles = rootFile.listFiles();
    for (File file : subFiles != null ? subFiles : new File[] {}) {
        if (file.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(fileToBeFound)) {
            return file;
        } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
            File f = findFile(file.getAbsolutePath(), fileToBeFound);
            if (f != null) {
                return f;
            }
        }
    }

    return null; // null returned in case your file is not found

}

public static void main(final String[] args){

     File fileToBeFound = findFile("C:\\", "INPUT.txt"); // search for the file in all the C drive
     System.out.println(fileToBeFound != null ? fileToBeFound.getAbsolutePath() : "Not found");

     //you can also use your current workspace directory, if you're sure the file is there
    fileToBeFound = findFile(new File(".").getAbsolutePath() , "INPUT.txt");
    System.out.println(fileToBeFound != null ? fileToBeFound.getAbsolutePath() : "Not found");
}
```